# Positioning etoc's \localtableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I am writing a long document and want to include local tables of contests after each chapter. This is easily achieved with the package [etoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) and the command `\localtableofcontents` being introduced just after the chapter definition `\chapter{Chapter One}`. However, I get the chapter's title in one page and the local table of contents on the next one. Is there are a way to anchor the LToC to the same page as the chapter's title?

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge}{\thechapter}{1.5em}{\MakeUppercase}{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\localtableofcontents
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One Point One}
\section{Section Two}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `etoc`'s features such as `\etocsettocstyle`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Huge}
  {\thechapter}
  {1.5em}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\etocsettocstyle{}{} % from now on only local tocs

\chapter{Chapter One}

\localtableofcontents

\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One Point One}
\section{Section Two}

\end{document}
```

The first and second arguments to `\etocsettocstyle` contain respectively what we want before and after the local TOC. Customize at will.

[image]

Comment: +1 and as alternative one can also issue `\etocarticlestyle` (after the main TOC) to instruct `etoc` to use the display style from article, not book class. Then it would use `\section*`,  not `\chapter*` for the TOC headings and there would be no new page.

Answer (score 2):

As pointet out by *egreg*, `\clearpage` is not in this class added by `\chapter`, but by `\localtableofcontents`. This could be disabled locally, with adding `\let\clearpage\relax`in front of it, within a group.

Also, his answer is probably better for this package. But this solution could work as a more general way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge}{\thechapter}{1.5em}{\MakeUppercase}{}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\chapter{Chapter One}
\let\clearpage\relax
\localtableofcontents
\endgroup
\clearpage
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One Point One}
\section{Section Two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you disable `\clearpage` just before `\localtableofcontents`?

Comment: @egreg Of course, you are right. Added some info reflecting this.

Comment: just to be precise the `\clearpage` is not explicitely added by the `etoc` code; it comes from a `\chapter*` which the document class (report) inserts as part of its code for the table of contents, and this code is inherited by `etoc`. The command `\etocarticlestyle` would tell `etoc` to use `\section*` rather, hence no `\clearpage`.